# IRLS working weights proportional odds

Tags: generalized-linear-model, least-squares, boosting, weighted-regression, ordered-logit

According to [Reduced-rank vector generalized linear models](http://smj.sagepub.com/content/3/1/15.abstract) the parameter estimates are obtained by Fisher-scoring algorithm. In the `VGAM` package the IRLS algorithm is used:

$\beta^{(a+1)} = (\sum X_i^\top W_i ^{(a)} X_i)^{-1} (\sum X_i^\top W_i ^{(a)} z_i^{(a)})$

My aim is to reproduce the IRLS steps by extracting the working weights $ W_i ^{(a)}$ for each step $a$ and then fit the parameters for the $(a+1)$-th step.
I am failing with the first step because the `vglm` function does not accept the working weights.

```
pneumo <- transform(pneumo, let = log(exposure.time))
fit1 <- vglm(cbind(normal, mild, severe) ~ let,
             cumulative(), data=pneumo, maxit=1)
weight1 <- weights(fit, type = "working") # working weights

# the weights can't be used to fit the second step
fit2 <- vglm(cbind(normal, mild, severe) ~ let,
             cumulative(), data=pneumo, maxit=1, weights=weight1)
weight2 <- weights(fit, type = "working")
```

`?vglm` tells me:
If the VGAM family function handles multiple responses (q > 1 of them, say) then weights can be a matrix with q columns. Each column matches the respective response.

`?weightsvglm` tells me:
Working weights are used by the IRLS algorithm. They correspond to the second derivatives of the log-likelihood function with respect to the linear predictors. The working weights correspond to positive-definite weight matrices and are returned in matrix-band form, e.g., the first M columns correspond to the diagonals, etc.